# Batch XCOPY with variables invalid path

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Okay, so this is my current code:

```
set path=%~dp0
set path1=%path:~0,-1%
for %%f in (%path1%) do set outPutFolder=%%~nxf
set outputPath=C:\Users\Steven\Google Drive\Backups\%outputFolder%\
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy "%path%" "%outputPath%" /E /D /W /F /Y
```

XCopy returns invalid path.  The paths appear to be correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When calling xcopy from absolute path, you should include an extension.  `%SystemRoot%\system32\xcopy.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say precisely what this code is intended to do, but try, in your `xcopy` `"%path%*"` in place of `"%path%"` which should copy all files to the destination

It's not a good idea to change `path` since `path` is established by Windows as a semicolon-separated list of directories that is searched for an executable if the executable does not exist in the current directory.

Comment: To change path? Is path a predefined variable. My program's purpose is to back up files from the folder it it located in to the cloud.

Comment: Thanks, the "*" made a very big difference.

Comment: Yes - `path` is a predefined variable with a special purpose.

Comment: At the command prompt, type `SET <enter>` and you will see the existing variables.